# ASCII and char programs

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string c;
cout << "Enter a character: ";
cin >> c;
cout << "ASCII Value of " << c << " is " << int(c);
return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

```
name error : ||=== Build: Debug in gfghf (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\gfghf\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\gfghf\main.cpp|10|error: invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'int'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Just redeclare c as char c; Otherwise this expression int(c) does not make sense and is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

just replace `string c;` with `char c;` as you just want to print ASCII value. taking `c` as `string` type doesn't make any sense.

```
int main() {
   char c;
   cout << "Enter a character: ";
   cin >> c;
   cout << "ASCII Value of " << c << " is " << int(c);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying the **data types** you used you may as well as try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string c;
cout << "Enter a character: ";
cin >> c;
cout << "ASCII Value of " << c << " is " << int(c[0]);

return 0;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

====================================================================

The reason why it did not accept int(c) was it was of the type string, and string is a collection of character

int(c[0])  // Tells the compiler that we are looking at a character as opposed 
                                                                to string

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this code?

It is apparently meant to read a single character but reads a whole string, and a string cannot be converted to an integer number with a simple cast.

Quick fix:

```
char c;
cout << "Enter a character: ";
cin >> c;
```

A more robust solution is to read a whole string of input, then check if the user actually entered only a single character, and then use that single character:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Enter a character: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    if (line.size() == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << line[0] << " is " << static_cast<int>(line[0]) << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a single character!\n";
    }
}
```

Also note that ASCII is not guaranteed by C++, although it probably is ASCII on your computer.